# MySQL update field with same ID

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table that has two different values for the same product id:

FROM `_term_relationships`

```
object_id   term_taxonomy_id 

3148        2   
3148        179     
3149        2   
3149        180
```

I want to change the first value (2) to 4 if the second value is 179.

How can I do this?

I'm currently using this query to change all of term_taxonomy_id fields with values of 2 to 4:

```
UPDATE
    infy_term_relationships 
    LEFT JOIN infy_posts ON ( infy_term_relationships.object_id = infy_posts.ID )
SET infy_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =4
WHERE
    infy_posts.post_type = 'product'
    AND infy_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =2
```

But now I need a dependency for category value that is 197.

Comment: Will object_id always repeat only 2 times??

Comment: no, some obiect_id have 4 values

Comment: this is the query what I use to change all of term_taxonomy_id fields with value of 2 to 4:  UPDATE infy_term_relationships LEFT JOIN infy_posts ON ( infy_term_relationships.object_id = infy_posts.ID )  SET infy_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =4 WHERE infy_posts.post_type = 'product' AND infy_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =2  but now I need a dependency for category value what is 197.

Comment: @Gunaseelan , none, I don`t know what is the logic to solve that.

Comment: Define 'first'. Define 'second'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find object_id int with to record 2 and 179 and for that object_id and term_taxonomy_id is equal 2 set term_taxonomy_id to 4

```
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (object_id int, term_taxonomy_id int);
insert into t1 values 
(3148,     2),
(3148,      179),  
(3149,       2), 
(3149,        180);

update t1 
  set term_taxonomy_id = 4 
  where term_taxonomy_id = 2 
    and object_id = 
        (select object_id 
           from (select object_id  
                   from t1 
                   group by object_id 
                   having concat(',',group_concat(term_taxonomy_id),',')  like  '%,2,179,%' 
                 ) as temp    
          );  

select * from t1
```

Comment: I think for me should be: UPDATE `infy_term_relationships` SET term_taxonomy_id =4 WHERE term_taxonomy_id =2 AND object_id = (
SELECT object_id
FROM (

SELECT object_id
FROM infy_term_relationships
GROUP BY object_id
HAVING group_concat( term_taxonomy_id ) = '2,179'
) AS temp
)      but returns 0 row affected

Comment: but in my mysql i see (3148, 4), 
(3148,      179),  
(3149,       2), 
(3149,        180);

Comment: Look what inner select returns

Comment: nothing :( but I don`t know where is the problem, the query looks ok, in the new created table (t1) does his job but no in the place where I need.

Comment: on that table ask `select group_concat(term_taxonomy_id) from infy_term_relationships  where  object_id  = 3148 group by object_id` . What is a result?

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0004 sec)
SELECT group_concat( term_taxonomy_id )
FROM infy_term_relationships
WHERE object_id =3148
GROUP BY object_id
LIMIT 0 , 30                                                                      group_concat(term_taxonomy_id)  
2,179,262,263,264

Comment: ie. found. And what output?

Comment: group_concat(term_taxonomy_id) 2,179,262,263,264

Comment: just a moment. i will try

Comment: I got the:  #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row    error

Comment: try now. if not, i pass :(

Comment: Something is wrong, but thank you anyway for your help